# linking a framework to project

Tags: xcode

For example to add a framework to workspace
 steps involved are:
1.Right click on the framework
2.select the Framework and click on Add

it will link  the respective framework to project

is there any other method to add the framework to project

Comment: Do you mean "target" when you say "project"? Xcode projects aren't built and linked, targets are.

Comment: i meant the workpace as project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. That's the preferred Apple way of doing it. Are you looking to do a different way for any specific reason?

Comment: just to know the alternate methods